# Data type instances?

Tags: haskell, types

Am I right in saying below is an illustration (a tediously simple one) of the use of data type instances? i.e. allows you to define different behaviors for different data.

If not, how else can these be used?

Code:

```
data HealthIndicators = Weight | Age | BloodPressure deriving (Show)
data IrrelevantIndicators = Starsign | BirthMonth | IQ deriving (Show)

class IndicatorTest a where
   indicatortest :: a -> Bool

instance IndicatorTest HealthIndicators where
   indicatortest Weight = True
   indicatortest Age = True
   indicatortest BloodPressure = True

instance IndicatorTest IrrelevantIndicators where
   indicatortest Starsign = False
   indicatortest BirthMonth = False
   indicatortest IQ = False
```

Comment: It makes it easy to define type-safe [equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), ordering, etc.  and that isn't even getting into the fact that type-classes can be over higher kinded types (like [monads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) or arrows)

Comment: Well, that's true but one would normally use two different functions. Or define two same-name functions in different modules. In the vast majority of cases, we don't need dynamic dispatch as in OOP. Still, your example is technically correct, but I find e.g. `Ord, Eq, Show, Monoid, ...` far more interesting and general. You may want to look at them.

Comment: Yes, one possible goal is to find common uses for different data types. This may well be uses the original author of said data types didn't even imagine. That being said, I'm not convinced that the example constitutes a nice data model.

Answer (score 0):

First, your instances don't need to list all the cases because they don't make any difference. You can write

```
instance IndicatorTest HealthIndicators where
   indicatortest _ = True
```

Or if you prefer, the second line can be

```
   indicatortest = const True
```

This might be useful if you are writing a function like this:

```
foo :: (IndicatorTest h) => h -> String
```

and you need the result to vary depending on whether the type `h` is a useful indicator or not. But in that case you would probably have made "foo" a function in the `IndicatorTest` class anyway.

Its a bit difficult to advise further without knowing what you are actually trying to achieve.